# Como fazer o envio de um formulário ao pressionar "enter"?

Tags: jquery

Como que eu faço um tipo de *click* para um `input` sem utilizar botão? Por exemplo, eu vou clicar no `input` digitar o que eu quero procurar e quando pressionar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> o formulário será enviado. Como que eu faço isso com jQuery?

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar" id="buscar" name="q" />
```

Comment: sim eu tenho a parte em php que retorna o que escrever nesse input vc quer que eu poste?

Comment: nao estou fazendo esta parte por ajax eu apenas queria verificar pra nao deixar passar em branco apenas isso o resto pode ficar do modo que esta

Comment: tipo eu sei verificar mas com um botao sem o botao so assim nao sei como que tipo forca um click sem o botao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da maneira abaixo ele vai verificar se algo foi escrito por meio da expressão regular `/\w/`, que ignora os espaços em branco.

**Exemplo editado:**

```js
$("#buscar").on("blur", function(e) {
  verify(e);
});
$("#buscar").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    verify(e);
  }
});

function verify(e) {
  if (!(/\w/.test($("#buscar").val()))) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('p').html('Preencha algo!');
  } else {
    $('p').html('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="buscar">
</form>
<p></p>
```

Eu usei a função  [blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) que é acionada ao usuário retirar o foco da `input`. Mas caso prefira o `click`, basta colocar `.on("click",`.

Comment: mas desse modo ele incia a busca ele abre o meu arquivo php nao sei se programei certo pq tipo eu quero que quando clicado ele vai verificar se tem algo digitado se nao tiver algo digitado ele nao faz nd

Comment: $("#buscar").on("keypress", function(e){
        var busca = $("#buscar").val();
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
        if(busca == ""){
            alert("test");
            return;
        }    
        $("form").submit(); //Seu form será submetido
        }
        });

Comment: seria desse modo que eu fiz verifiquei antes do submit

Comment: hum.. Imagino que tenha entendido. Mas @LeonardoCosta, a função `click` em uma ciaxa de texto é um tanto estranha, será que você não prefere um `blur`?

Comment: Irei editar a resposta com alguns exemplos adicionais.

Comment: blur nunca usei nem sei como usa mas eu so queria isso msm nao enviar o form so pra verificar se ele ta preenchido

Comment: Resposta editada @LeonardoCosta

Comment: disso eu sei mas quero algo mais visual mostrar um alert personalizado essas coisa

Comment: @SamirBraga nisso e so quando eu tirar o focus do input nao vai com enter?

Comment: cara eu falei que nao quero enviar o form eu quero verficar quando der enter se tem algo escrito no input se tiver algo escrito sim ele vai e executa o form se nao tiver nada escrito ele da um alert pedindo para escrever

Comment: intendeu @renan?

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, da maneira que está, está bom? Basta apenar colocar a função para ser excutado também o enter? Ou falta algo mais?

Comment: tipo eu so queria pra ser executado com o enter mas sem enviar o formulario @SamirBraga

Comment: quando eu der o enter ele vai entrar na minha verificacao se esta preenchido aquele input se estiver preenchido o input ele vai submeter o form se o input estiver vazio ele vai dar um alert sem submeter o form intendeu?

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, imagino que da maneira que coloquei agora deve dar tudo certinho

Comment: perfeito @SamirBraga!

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado :).

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa capturar se o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> foi digitado no `input`, pois quando a tecla enter é pressionada dentro de um elemento de entrada em um formulário, por padrão o formulário será enviado.

O que você precisa fazer é prevenir que o formulário seja enviado e para isto pode usar o [**`event#preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/event/preventDefault):

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#buscar').on('submit', function(event) {
    // Prevenindo a ação padrão (enviar o formulário).
    event.preventDefault();

    // Pegando o valor inserido no input.
    var searchFor = $(this).find('input').val();

    if (!searchFor) {
      alert("Form ñ enviado porque...");
    } else {
      alert("Form enviado.");
      // $(this).submit();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--
  - Trocando o '#buscar' para o formulário, ao invés do input.
  -->
<form id='buscar'>
  <input type='search' placeholder='Buscar por...' />
</form>
```

Comment: Uma ótima opção!